# Linear and Binary search using iterator position

Tags: c++, binary-search, linear-search

I am writing two functions, the first one does a linear search and is supposed to return the position of the first found value if it is in the vector. The second method is a binary search that is done using equal_range and it is supposed to return the same thing as the linear search. Currently they are checking every value as a match. Any help is appreciated.

```
int linearSearch( const vector<int>& vec, int z)
{
   vector<int>::iterator iter = find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), z);

   if (iter != vec.end())
      return (iter-vec.begin());

   else
      return -1;
}

int binarySearch( const vector<int>& vec, int z)
{
    pair<vector<int>::const_iterator, vector<int>::const_iterator> bounds;

    bounds = equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(), z);

    if (bounds.first != vec.end())
       return (bounds.first -vec.begin());

    else
       return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your description is unclear, but I'll point out some concerns with the code.

In `binarySearch()` search, there is

```
bounds = equal_range(vec.begin(),vec.end(), z);

if (bounds.first != v.end())
   return (bounds.first -v.begin());
```

`v` is not declared anywhere.   If the code compiles then, presumably, it is declared somewhere in code you haven't shown.   But it may have no relationship to `vec`.    The behaviour of the code (particularly the `return`) will be undefined.

A rather fundamental difference between the functions is because `std::equal_range()` assumes a sorted (or partitioned) range, and `std::find()` does not.

Comment: Sorry it should have been vec.begin, I edited it

Comment: I need this code to output the position of the found value in the vector